# How does the copy module understand where to check for src and dest directories?

Tags: ansible

This might not be a valid question. I was going through source of [copy module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/library/files/copy) at github.
While I could understand what and how it is doing one thing I am not able to get. I see following two lines

```
if not os.path.exists(src)
```

and

```
if os.path.exists(dest):
```

While I get that these lines are checking the presence of source and dest directories, how does python knows where to look these on as they are on different machines (the ansible server and host). How does python differentiates them and looks for them on their repective machines?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think this copy module (liblary/file/copy) doesn't work.

Usually, when we use a command like this,

```
ansible webservers -m copy -a "src=/tmp/foo.conf dest=/tmp/bar.conf"
```

ansible will use [this runnner module(lib/ansible/runner/action_plugins/copy.py)](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/runner/action_plugins/copy.py) preferentially.

I tried running the same command, hiding the runner module. Then, (ansible/liblary/file/copy) module was executed. However, this did not do the work that is expected. There are several problems, this code is one of a cause.

```
if not os.path.exists(src)
if os.path.exists(dest):
```

Both check the file on the remote host.